# Stream to Xbox 360 from PC network share?

Tags: xbox-360

I am finding that some video files do not play on the Xbox 360 video player when streamed from a PC on the network.  The error given is that the format is unsupported.

If I put these video files on to a USB drive I find that they play.

Is there a way to have the video player just stream from a network share?  I think the PC media player is interferring with the streaming in some way.  I just want the video player to just transfer and stream the file from the PC.  Is this possible?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with a missing codec.  In situations like this I installed the missing codec on my system and the video played perfectly through the Microsoft Media Center application on the XBOX 360.

Answer (score 2):

It might sound odd, but the PS3 Mediaserver works with the Xbox. You can configure it to your folder of videos and just play them from the Video Center in your Xbox360. The PS3 Media Server will stream the video to your Xbox. It'll work as long as your computer can play the video as well. See this page http://www.homemultimedianetwork.com/Guides/Installing-PS3-Media-Server.php

Comment: +1, I've used this to great effect. It's a very good media streamer in its own right.

Comment: Absolutely. Just have to start the application on the computer and hit the video player in xbox, and the whole list of movies pops up :)

Answer (score 0):

Try what Ramhound said, and maybe you have to activate upnp and/or dlna in your router's settings. You could also try XMBC or Plex to see if that works. (XBMC and Plex are programs that allow you to stream media over the network, they are both free)